# How to import a .obj with a .mlt into Maya?

Tags: unity-game-engine, maya, .obj

I have a folder with a .obj file, a .mlt file, and a number of .jpgs that are textures for the .obj file. [Here's a link](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/8ghf6ksnbqgdnvz/AACguN1jC-qX9Ay1ZE1Z3lLBa?dl=0) to the folder.

I'm trying to import this .obj into either Maya or Unity 3D, and when I do I only see a gray, untextured object. How can I get my model to appear with the textures/materials in the folder? From what I gather from elsewhere on the web, .mlt files are sort of tricky to work with in combination with .objs, but is there anything I can do here that will let me get this model to render properly with these materials in Maya or Unity 3D?

Grateful for any help.

Answer (score 1):

From what I've seen online as well, Maya doesn't play nice with .mlt files. I think the best solution is to grab a copy of [Maya LT](http://www.autodesk.com/products/maya-lt/overview) (or download the trial), open your .obj w/ .mlt, and use the [FBX plugin](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/maya-lt/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2017/ENU/MayaLT/files/GUID-18A2CDD7-3334-4FC1-A1B3-A308AD331BB2-htm.html) (built-in) to export a .fbx file which is compatible with both Maya and Unity.

Comment: Thanks for responding! I have Maya so that's no problem, but how do I open the .obj file with the .mlt? Maya doesn't seem to be able to read it.

Comment: Following [this](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/maya-lt/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2017/ENU/MayaLT/files/GUID-DC183670-EF0F-4E69-AEDF-69D408D82408-htm.html) info link, you'll need to use File > Open Scene, and in the file dialog select the .mlt file.